# How do you validate a bitcoin address using bitcoinjs library in javascript?

Tags: bitcoinjs, validation

How would one validate a bitcoin address using the bitcoinjs library? Or is there another way to do this via javascript?

Comment: Do you mean for a website or app? Or do you just want to personally verify one?

Comment: for a website im working on. I have bitcoinjs library loaded, but not sure what function to call to check if a btc address is valid or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you call

```
bitcoin.address.toOutputScript(address, bitcoin.networks.bitcoin)
```

It will throw an error if the address cannot be parsed as P2SH or P2PKH, or if the checksum is not valid. Replace the second argument with `bitcoin.networks.testnet` for testnet.